# Encaminando Vagrant

Tags: servidor, vagrant

estoy empezando con Vagrant y creo que voy algo perdido.

Os cuento el escenario, a ver si podéis encaminarme de una forma correcta.

2 entornos con 2 máquinas online:

- staging
- produccion

Estas 2 máquinas tienen instalado GIT.

Somos 4 usuarios para trabajar con un Vagrant con Ubuntu 14.04 con LAMP instalado.

La idea es mapear una carpeta local para que se muestre por el puerto 8080 para trabajar mediante localhost:8080

Como hago para crear un box con Ubuntu + LAMP y para aprovisionar cada Vagrant de cada usuario con dicho box?

Como hago para poder incluir en la config de Vagrant los ss-key de cada usuario para que puedan subir mediante GIT a las máquinas remotas de staging + produccion?

No se como enforcar esta config.. si con YAML o en el Vagrantfile.

Gracias.

Comment: No se entiende muy bien si los cuatro accedéis al mismo Vagrant o si cada uno tiene el suyo propio...

Comment: La idea es que cada uno tenga el suyo propio. La config del Vagrant bajo un repo, para que todos puedan actualizar la config si hay cambios desde una misma fuente. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para crear un *box* con *Ubuntu+LAMP* te sugiero utilizar la *box* de *Ubuntu* mantenida por *Ubuntu*, por ejemplo:

https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64

... y en la sección `provision` ejecutar los pasos que faltan para tener el *LAMP*:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get update
apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php mysql-server
```

De esta forma, la imagen la mantiene *Ubuntu* y tú siempre instalas la última versión de los paquetes al empezar tu jornada de desarrollo.

Los códigos de la aplicación los puedes tener en el `host` bajo un sub-directorio donde está tu *Vagranfile*, por ejemplo, `app/` y te quedará dentro de la *VM* en `/vagrant/app` que puedes *sym-linkear* a *DocumentRoot* del *Apache*:

```
rm -R /var/www/hmtl 
ln -s /vagrant/app /var/www/html
```

... y puedes trabajar con tus herramientas de edición (*IDE*, *GIT*, etc.) que tengas en tu host; pues es la idea de *Vagrant*: Que trabajes y programes en el ambiente y herramientas conocidos, siendo *Vagrant* un simple medio para correr/probar/integrar la aplicación.

Otra cosa que puede configurar rápidamente tu entorno de desarrollo es [Vaprobash](http://fideloper.github.io/Vaprobash/index.html) que descomentando un par de líneas te va a dejar el *LAMP* instalado.